# Facebook login "given URL not allowed by application configuration"

Tags: facebook, url, authentication

I've added facebook login to my site.  However, when I click the button, I get a red box that says:

```
Invalid Argument

Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.
```

If I continue to login then I get:

```
API Error Code: 100
API Error Description: Invalid parameter
Error Message: next is not owned by the application.
```

Not sure exactly what the problem is.  Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Your settings must be incorrect.

Go to http://www.facebook.com/developers/ and edit the application you're working on.

On the "website" tab, look for "Site URL". This should be set to your website's URL "http://yoursite.com/"

Note that if you're using subdomains, you'll also need to update "Site Domain" to be "yoursite.com"

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Yeah ... that's what I thought, but have this: http://www.zaboof.com/ for website's URL and this: zaboof.com for the site domain.  Hmm ....  Any other thoughts?

Comment: I'm wondering if I didn't set the next URL (I'm assuming this is the URL that we go to after login) correctly?

Comment: Never mind.  I'm an idiot!  The problem was that I was testing the login locally, so needed a localhost URL in application config settings.  Thanks very much for you're help.

Comment: @joe: no problem! To test everything properly you might want to open some kind of tunnel so that facebook doesn't have to handle local URLs  and possibily break because of that

Comment: @joe: you'll need some kind of server ~ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunneling_protocol

Comment: @marcgg so is there no way to use a custom protocol for your facebook callback?

Comment: @schwiz: I think that nowadays you can set a secure URL. Not sure though.

Answer (score 27):

You can set up a developer application and set the url to localhost.com:port
Make sure to map localhost.com to localhost on your hosts file

Works for me

Comment: very useful for testing during development

Comment: Can someone please provide instructions on how to do this? I haven't been able to figure it out from the above (or from Googling).

Comment: In your facebook app info, in "Site URL" change it to localhost.com, then in your hosts file (look here to know where your file is located: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)#Location_in_the_file_system) add an entry "127.0.0.1 localhost.com". That way when you access localhost.com it will go to 127.0.0.1 which is your local machine. Hope this helps!

Comment: FYI... port is not required. In FB App Settings under "App Domains" add "local.yourdomain.com" (now needs to be a sub-set of the configured Site URL in Website platform config)... configure hosts as described here local.yourdomain.com 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 4):

Also check to see if you are missing the www in the url which was on my case

i was testing on http://www.mywebsite.com and in the facebook app i had set 
http://mywebsite.com

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this problem while using a tunnel because I:

1. had the tunnel url:port set in
   the FB app settings
2. but was
   accessing the local server by
   pointing my browser to
   "http://localhost:3000"

once i started punching the tunnel url:port into the browser, i was good to go.

i'm using Rails and Facebooker, but might help others just the same.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/

for me worked

https://apps.facebook.com/YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE (watch fot http:// or https:// issue)

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting this error, when using wildcard subdomains with my app.
I had the site url set to: http://myapp.com and app domain also to http://myapp.com, and also the same value for the Valid OAuth redirect URIs in the advanced tab of the settings app.
I tried different combinations but only setting the http://subdomain.myapp.com as the redirect value worked, of course only for that subdomain.

The solution was to empty the redirect fields, leave it blank, that worked! ;)