# configure mvc.net application on facebook

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have integrated facebook in my application mvc.net application. 
I have configured my apllication on face book
with the url : http://localhost:portnumber/Home/Test?Return="ok"

when i run the application then it opened pop up of facebook having two text boexs for user name and password with warning message:
"Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration"

In my application Test is the name of Action method of controller

Please suggest me how to handle this.

Thanks

Munish

Answer (score 0):

[Facebook login "given URL not allowed by application configuration"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610858/facebook-login-given-url-not-allowed-by-application-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that's because you're giving `localhost` as the host name to Facebook? You'll need a public URL, localhost is private to your machine, so it can't be seen remotely...

Answer (score 0):

i think you should only indicate the domain for example:
 http://localhost:portnumber/

without the action and url paramters.