# Gigya Integration Help Needed

Tags: facebook, gigya

I am trying to develop a new site using gigya for facebook integration

for that i have created a facebook application

then updated my gigya settings like `app id` and `secret id`

Grabbed the facebook login plugin code used in my html/jsp, and I am seeing the ‘facebook’ button on the jsp page

When I click on the ‘facebook’ button, its opening a new window and connecting to facebook, but I am seeing below  error consistently

> {
>      "error": {
>         "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.",
>         "type": "OAuthException",
>         "code": 191
>      }
>   }

My environment information given below:

1. Using JBoss App Server
2. I have a host name like local.test.me [updated my host file]
3. I accessed the page like http://local.test.me:8080/test.html

did i miss something??

Answer (score 1):

Gigya has documentation about this:

http://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/Facebook

And other posts in SO here:

[Facebook login "given URL not allowed by application configuration"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610858/facebook-login-given-url-not-allowed-by-application-configuration)