# Facebook local development not working

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication

I'm at my wit's end trying to get this to work.  It used to, but for some reason seems like it's broken again.  I'm only having trouble when developing locally.  Is anyone else currently having similar issues with Facebook local development?

These are my steps:

1. Create an app
2. Under the 'Basic Info' section, set 'localhost' as the domain (I have also tried leaving this blank)
3. Set my website to `http://localhost:8080/`
4. Make sure sandbox mode is OFF
5. My local server is running Javascript at `http://localhost:8080/private/` that looks basically like below.
6. I have also tried using a substitute for localhost (like myapp.com), defining it in etc/hosts file mapped to 127.0.0.1, setting the App Domain to 'myapp.com' and using the site 'http://myapp.com:8080/' with no luck.

FB.getLoginStatus() call is not returning, or only returns occasionally.  It always works on the production server.

```
    function myAppInit() {

        console.log("Facebook loaded; initializing sdk.");

        //Initialize FB SDK
        FB.init({ 
            appId:_FbAppId, //This is valid and matches app ID
            cookie:true, 
            status:true, 
            xfbml:true,
            oauth:true
        });

        //Query for login status.
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            updateLoginStatus(response);  //This is hit randomly
        });

        //Set our standard callback for auth change status
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
           updateLoginStatus(response);   //This is hit randomly
        });    
    }


    $(document).ready(function(){

        window.fbAsyncInit = myAppInit;
        (function(d){
             var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
             js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
             js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
             d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
        }(document));
     }
```

EDIT: After checking the response for FB.getLoginStatus(..), it is returning this:

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or
>   more of the given URLs is not allowed by the Application
>   configuration. It must match one of the Connect or Canvas URLs or
>   domain must be the same as or a subdomain of one of the
>   Application's base domains.

Comment: The right address (localhost:8080/private) is loaded in the canvas iframe? You're not getting an error, the *getLoginStatus* is just not returning any response? Are you sure the method was executed?

Comment: I'm not testing this through the FB canvas - this is loading a webpage directly at http://localhost:8080/private.  I'm sure the call is executed because I have a breakpoint on it in Firebug.

Comment: Add a 2nd parameter to the *getLoginStatus*, like: *FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) { ... }, true)* and check in the network tab in firebug what's the request and response

Comment: Thanks for point me at how to do this - I've added the error response above (which makes no sense, since I've added localhost as a domain on the page)

Comment: Ok, let's make sure: in the app settings your website is "localhost:8080/", in the app domain you have "localhost" and you are directing the browser to "localhost:8080/private", Is that correct? Also, make sure that you are using the right app id and not an id of some other app you might have.

Comment: Yep, that's what I have.  I did eventually get this to work, but I have no idea how - it seems random.  It seems as if when I created the app, it remembered the first domain I used, and only works on that specified domain, so I have to use that in my etc/hosts file.  Doesn't make any sense, but I won't tempt fate any more.

Comment: Possible dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610858/facebook-login-given-url-not-allowed-by-application-configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same exact error that you are describing and it was driving me nuts. You have to make sure that your Facebook URL in your Canvas or Page URL matches **EXACTLY** what you are typing in the browser.

In my case, I added a "www" to the URL in my address bar (e.g wwww.domain.com/MyApp), but under the Facebook Developer settings I just had domain.com/MyApp as my Page URL without the www prefix. That subtle difference is what was causing the error. Something may be happening similarly in your case.

If you are testing via localhost, I recommend creating a new app and making it a test version of your production app. That way, you can have your PROD url and your TEST url under the respective app in order that things don't get messy.

Also, I recommend debugging using IIS with a custom virtual directory so that you run on port 80. (Facebook seems to act goofy sometimes if you use anything other than 443 or 80) Hope that helps you.