# Facebook Api Integration for Social Lead Freak

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, integration

I'm total newbie in fb marketing, first time tried to create fb app to integrate it in social lead freak and social interest freak. I followed [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/eeQSQkAEa3I) but I got the error code:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 191
   }
}
```

Why is this going wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to include the code you've written, it's usually not possible to answer a question without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is related to your App configuration inside FB platform - as mentioned in other questions:

[Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration Facebook application error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098952/given-url-is-not-allowed-by-the-application-configuration-facebook-application-e)

> > Try to check at Settings > Advanced. At Valid OAuth redirect URIs, make sure you have a correct domain or let it empty (not recommended)

[Facebook login "given URL not allowed by application configuration"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610858/facebook-login-given-url-not-allowed-by-application-configuration)

> > Your settings must be incorrect.
> >     Go to http://www.facebook.com/developers/ and edit the application you're working on.
> >     On the "website" tab, look for "Site URL". This should be set to your website's URL "http://yoursite.com/"
> >     Note that if you're using subdomains, you'll also need to update "Site Domain" to be "yoursite.com"